# Solve for Theta: $a = b\tan(\theta) - \frac{c}{\cos(\theta)}$

Tags: trigonometry

The title pretty much sums it up. How do I solve for $\theta$ given the following equation.

$a = b\tan(\theta) - \frac{c}{\cos(\theta)}$

I am not a student and this is not homework.  It's been quite a while since I've done any significant trig and I'm out of time to figure this out.